# Settings stored in Room table with one entry trigger all observers on any parameter update

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am using simple Room table for settings

```
@Entity
data class Settings(var user: String = "") {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long = 1

    var activeItem: Int = 0
    var developerMode: Boolean = false
    var logoUrl: String = ""
    var advertisment: String = ""
}
```

And I observe changes in table with LiveData. Problem is that if all data are in one entry with id = 1 then All observers are triggered always when any value in table is updated. Is there any way how to force LiveData to observe only when parameter is changed, not whole entry ?
I do not want to solve it via additional table or to store it in entries with different ID's

Here are querys from Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT activeItem FROM Settings WHERE id = 1")
abstract fun getActiveItem(): LiveData<Int>

@Query("SELECT user FROM Settings WHERE id = 1")
abstract fun getUser(): LiveData<String>

@Query("SELECT developerMode FROM Settings WHERE id = 1")
abstract fun getDeveloperMode(): LiveData<Boolean>

@Query("SELECT logoUrl FROM Settings WHERE id = 1")
abstract fun getLogoUrl(): LiveData<String>

@Query("SELECT advertisment FROM Settings WHERE id = 1")
abstract fun getAdvertisment(): LiveData<String>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) for persist user preferences. You can listen for preferences update by preference change listener

```
preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { sharedPreferences, key -> 
    // handle preference update
}
```

or you can implement your own preference registry.

---

1. Define your preference models as `sealed class`

   ```
   sealed class MyPreference

   data class ActiveItemPreference(val number: Int) : MyPreference()
   data class UserPreference(val name: String, val age: Int) : MyPreference()
   ```
2. Implement `PreferenceRegistry` as *typesafe heterogeneous container (Effective Java (3rd). Item 33)*

   ```
   object PreferencesRegistry {

       private val preferenceLiveDataMap: Map<KClass<*>, MutableLiveData<MyPreference>> =
               HashMap<KClass<*>, MutableLiveData<MyPreference>>().apply {
                   addPreferenceLiveData(ActiveItemPreference::class)
                   addPreferenceLiveData(UserPreference::class)
                   /*
                    Or you if you use kotlin-reflect you can register your preferences like this
                   Preference::class.sealedSubclasses.forEach { preferenceClass ->
                       addPreferenceLiveData(preferenceClass)
                   }
                   */
               }

       operator fun <T : MyPreference> get(preferenceType: KClass<T>): LiveData<T> {
           @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") val liveData = preferenceLiveDataMap[preferenceType] as? LiveData<T>
           return liveData ?: throw AssertionError("Unexpected preference type $preferenceType")
       }

       /**
        * Store receiver [T] of [toPreferences] extension to receiver [SharedPreferences] of [action]
        */
       fun <T : MyPreference> T.toPreferences(context: Context, action: SharedPreferences.(T) -> Unit) {
           // get shared preferences to store T
           context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).action(this)
           // send new value of preference T to observers
           preferenceLiveDataMap[this::class]?.postValue(this) ?: AssertionError(
                   "Unable to update preference live data of type ${this::class}")
       }

       /**
        * Helper extension for type safety
        */
       private fun <T : MyPreference> MutableMap<KClass<*>, MutableLiveData<MyPreference>>.addPreferenceLiveData(type: KClass<T>) {
           put(type, MutableLiveData())
       }
   }
   ```

   Look at `toPreferences` extension implemented in DSL manner, you can read more about this approach in *Kotlin in Action book (item 11.2.1)* or in [Type-Safe Builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html#type-safe-builders) article.
3. Now you can save your properties

   ```
   UserPreference("Tom", 12).toPreferences(context) { (name, age) ->
       // extension for SharedPreferences from Android SDK
       edit {
           putString("USER_NAME", name)
           putInt("USER_AGE", age)
       }
   }
   ```
4. And observe changes

   ```
   PreferencesRegistry[UserPreference::class].observe(this::getLifecycle) { userPref ->
       if (userPref == null)
           Log.w("PREFERENCES", "Unexpected nullable user preference")
       else
           Log.d("PREFERENCES", "User preference updated. New name is ${userPref.name} and new age is ${userPref.age}")
   }
   ```
5. Implement preferences loading and call it on application startup

Comment: I am already using Room with about 10 tables including backup restore functionality, I do not want to include any other storage. I want to solve the issue with observing one settings table via LiveData